# Bootstrap 5: div different align for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, alignment, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap 5 website template where I want to display divs in these order:

DESKTOP:

1st line of divs: image, text

2nd line of divs: text, image

[image]

MOBILE:

1st line of divs: image, text

2nd line of divs: image, text

[image]

Simply said, there should be different order/alignment of every second line of divs for mobile devices. Could you please help me how to achieve it? I've tried to use several bootstrap classes, or even hardcode float left and right. Nothing helped. Here's my code:

```
    <!-- Img1 -->
      <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/img1.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center align-items-center mob_padding_T20" style="color: #FF0000;">
              Copy1
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- Img2 -->
      <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100" style="padding: 20px 0 0;">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float:right;">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/img2.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center align-items-center mob_padding_T20" style="float:left; color: #FF0000;">
          Copy2
        </div>
      </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Working on this now,but your image tag should end like this />

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution:

```html
<div className="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
        <div className="col-6">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" className="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-6 text-center align-items-center mob_padding_T20" >
          Copy1
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100" style={{ padding: "20px 0 0" }}>
        <div className="col-6 text-center align-items-center mob_padding_T20" style={{ float: "left", color: "#FF0000" }}>
          Copy2
        </div>
        <div className="col-6" style={{ float: "right" }}>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" className="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="" />
        </div>

      </div>
```

#### Your Problem:

The problem was that when you specified the column sized for your divs you used col-md-6 this will only be applied to medium-sized screens and larger. Here is a link explaining [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for quick reply, however, it doesn't work as expected on smaller device, my description was wrong for mobile (however, the screenshot is correct). It should display as below:


MOBILE:

1st line of div: image; 

2nd line of div: text; 

3rd line of div: image; 

4th line of div: text

Comment: Alright, well it seems dipesh has answered your revised question now

Comment: what really helped me here was that link for bootstrap grid documentation. All I needed to set were these 2 classes for the <div> with the second copy: _order-sm-first order-last_. That resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this one**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100"">
  <!--  Start Img 1  -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <img src="assets/img/portfolio/img1.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt=""> IMG 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Text 1
    </div>
  <!--  End  Img 1  -->
    
  <!--  Start Img 2  -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="assets/img/portfolio/img1.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt=""> IMG 2
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
     Text 2
    </div>
    <!--  End  Img 2  -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100"">
  <!--  Start Img 1  -->
    <div class="col-6">
       <img src="assets/img/portfolio/img1.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt=""> IMG 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      Text 1
    </div>
  <!--  End  Img 1  -->
    
  <!--  Start Img 2  -->
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="assets/img/portfolio/img1.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt=""> IMG 2
    </div>
     <div class="col-6">
     Text 2
    </div>
    <!--  End  Img 2  -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**SUGGESTION**: Please don't use inline CSS (style:: float:left or float:right) because it's very difficult to manage responsive devices.

If you don't need the second row then please remove it and use the direct col-sm/col-md/col class because it affects in SEO.

If you display text + img in single line then you can use col-6 in bootstrap 5.

Please review it codepen URL. I have provided you both examples  in codepen.

*Please let me know if you have any further question.*

Answer (score 0):

**SUGGESTION:** Avoid using inline CSS (style:: float:left or float:right) because managing responsive devices is quite challenging.

Because it affects SEO, please remove the second row if you don't require it and use the direct col-sm/col-md/col class instead.

Use col-6 in bootstrap 5 if you want to display text and an image on a single line.

Review it here:  run code snippe .

In case you have any other queries, kindly let me know.

Please review it codepen URL. I have provided you both examples in codepen.

Please let me know if you have any further question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="col-lg-6 p-3 order-sm-1 order-md-1 bg-primary">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MSRAJAWAT298/msrajawat298/main/images/background-images/msrajawat298_bg-min.png" width="75px" cla ss="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 p-3 text-center align-items-center mob_padding_T20 order-sm-2 order-md-2 float-end bg-info" style="color:red">Copy1</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 p-3 order-sm-4 order-md-4 bg-danger">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MSRAJAWAT298/msrajawat298/main/images/background-images/msrajawat298_bg-min.png" width="75px" class="rounded mx-auto d-block " alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 p-3 text-center align-items-center mob_padding_T20 order-sm-3 order-md-3 bg-dark" style="color:red">Copy2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```